# Confusion with background threads

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, background-thread

I have two AsyncTasks, one is used to download xml file (DownloadTask), another is for parsing the file (ParseXMLTask).
There are two cases of using this tasks:

1) File doesn't exists > execute DownloadTask, onPostExecute > ParseXMLTask

2) File exists > execute only ParseXMLTask.

Everything is working, but the thing is, while performing **the second case**, there is a blocking the ui about 3 sec (black screen) that surely would make a user annoyed. This is absolutely confusing me, because the job in the second case seems to be easier.

So when I am testing my app, a situation is like that: I click on the button for the first time, file is being downloaded, saved on the sd card, parsed and finally opened. Then I go back and click on the button again. Now I see that lag while switching between activities.

Code:

**Executing the tasks**

```
private void downloadPack() {
    if (packDownloaded) {
        parseXML();
    } else {    
        download = new DownloadFile(fileName, this, loadingBar);
        download.execute(serverURL + fileName + ".xml");
    }
}

private void parseXML() {
    ParseXMLTask parseTask = new ParseXMLTask(this, this);
    parseTask.execute(PATH + fileName + ".xml");
}

public void postDownload(File result) {
        parseXML();     
}   

public void postParse() {               
    Intent packIntent = new Intent(this, PackActivity.class);
    startActivity(packIntent);      
}
```

**ParseXMLTask.java**

```
public class ParseXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {    

private Context context;
private XmlPullParser xpp;
private IPostParse iPostParse;

public ParseXMLTask(Context context, IPostParse iPostParse) {
    this.context = context;
    this.iPostParse = iPostParse;

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {               
    File file = new File(params[0]);

    /* doing the job */
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Intent result) {
    iPostParse.postParse(result);
}
}
```

**DownloadFile.java**

```
public class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, File> {

private static final String PATH = Environment
        .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/.chgkgame/";;
private File dir;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private String fileName;
private IPostDownload postDownload;
private boolean download;


public DownloadFile(String name, IPostDownload pDownload, ProgressBar pBar) {
    progressBar = pBar;
    fileName = name;
    postDownload = pDownload;
}


@Override
protected File doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();            
        int fileLength = urlConnection.getContentLength();

        dir = new File(PATH + fileName + ".xml");
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(dir);

        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return dir;
}

@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(File result) {
    if (postDownload != null) postDownload.postDownload(result);
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    if (progressBar != null) {
        progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How have you come to the conclusion it is blocking the UI? What do you expect the screen to be doing?

Comment: During the execution of tasks I want to see my layout with the progress bar. But I can see the layout only about 1ms, than the black screen, and then the activity is called.

Comment: I do not see any onPreExecute() function in your DownloadFile class, which I believe that is where your progressBar should have been called `show()`. Are you initializing it before downloadPack() is called? If yes, can you show us also that part of code?

Comment: `loadingBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingBar);` before the `downloadPack()` method.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the above.

The parsing is pretty fast that is why you only see the layout for a split second.

The black screen will be the `PackActivity` loading, **check this activity** for what is blocking the UI thread.

You could have also put LogCat messages in to show that the parsing has finished and onCreate of the next Activity is called.